# ASP MVC 5 testing RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd

I'm testing whether a controller doesn't have a parameter, it should redirect to action `"Index"`.

```
// Controller code
return RedirectToAction("Index");

// Unit test code
ActionResult result = Controller.Action(null);
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));
Assert. // HERE i need to test it is going to Index, how do I do that?
```

Comment: The *RedirectToRouteResult* has the property `public RouteValueDictionary RouteValues { get; private set; }` you can check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into the RouteValues dictionary like so:

```
Assert.AreEqual("Index", (result as RedirectToRouteResult).RouteValues["action"]);
```